# How to response from a function inside a post function in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, post, request

i have 3 functions, each inside the other and i want to response from the last function.

Is the first function (nodejs post function):

```
router.post('/urls', (req, response) => {
  count = 2;
  webUrl = req.body.url;
  depth = req.body.depth;
  if (bool) {
   letstart(webUrl, count);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Finish");
  }
})
```

Is the second function (request library function):

```
function letstart(urlLink, counter) {
  if (counter <= depth) {
    request(urlLink, function (error, res, body) {
      console.error('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', res && res.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      //console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      if (!error) {
        getLinks(body);
      }
      else {
        console.log("sorry");
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    bool = false;
  }
}
```

and this this the last function:

```
function getLinks(body) {
  let allLists = [];
  const html = body;
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const linkObjects = $('a');
  const links = [];
  linkObjects.each((index, element) => {
    var strHref = $(element).attr('href');
    var strText = $(element).text();
    var tel = strHref.startsWith("tel");
    var mail = strHref.startsWith("mailto");
    var linkInStart = strHref.startsWith("http");
    if (strText !== '' && strText !== "" && strText !== null && strHref !== '' && strHref !== "" && strHref !== null && strHref !== undefined) {
      if (!tel && !mail) {
        if (linkInStart) {
          links.push({
            text: $(element).text(), // get the text
            href: $(element).attr('href'), // get the href attribute
          });
          linkslinst.push($(element).attr('href'))
        }
        else {
          links.push({
            text: $(element).text(), // get the text
            href: webUrl.toString() + $(element).attr('href'), // get the href attribute
          });
          linkslinst.push(webUrl.toString() + $(element).attr('href'))
        }
      }
    }
  });
  const result = [];
  const map = new Map();
  count++;
  for (const item of links) {
    if (!map.has(item.href)) {
      map.set(item.href, true);    // set any value to Map
      result.push({
        text: item.text,
        href: item.href
      });
    }
  }
  resArray.push({ list: result, depth: count - 1 });
}
```

I just want to response the "resArray" to react-App.js so i think that i need first of all to return this array to the post function.
How can i do this?

Comment: How about returning the result of each function? None of them return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to pass `response` as a parameter to `letstart` and then to `getLinks` so you would be able to use it at the end of `getLinks`, but this solutions is quite dirty and would make those two functions hard to reuse.

A better thing to do would be to make `letstart` return a `Promise`, and resolve it with `body`. Then make `getLinks` return `resArray`. You'll be able to call those two functions and get their results directly in the post function where you have `response`.

Learn more about Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: i passed the response and its succeeded but not a synchronous. I tried to add the promise. I added async to `letstart` and await to `getLinks` but its showed me: `"await is only valid in async function"`

Comment: You need to add `async` to the parent function, here the response function. `async (req, response)`

Comment: I tried that and it's still does'nt work. Maybe i need to add all the function there async/await?